# upsampling by huge factor

Tags: interpolation, supersampling

Assume i have a discrete signal, which i want to up-sample by factor 100.
Up-sampling using poly-phase algorithm sounds like a bad idea, in terms of cache low-efficiency due to low space-locality of the data.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Itay

Comment: i have absolutely no idea what is meant by *"low space-locality of the data"*.  and having done bandlimited sample interpolation for a variety of different applications, i have little idea what's wrong with using the normal polyphase FIR interpolation.  it's about the most efficient method if you want phase-linearity or "reversibility" (i.e. the interpolation result is the same whether you do it in the forward or backward direction).

Answer (score 2):

Upsampling by 100 can be factored into upsampling by 2X, 2X, 5X and 5X for each output block (output blocks sized to be data cache resident), thus requiring a smaller phase table for each FIR interpolation kernel.

Some output points may either need to be overlapped across blocks or re-calculated, depending on computation speed vs cache load latency.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a multirate structure where the stages have increasingly wider transition bands. This is very close to the situation answered in [another question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/134/how-can-i-design-a-very-narrow-filter/144#144)